# How to check to see if a key exists before trying to insert it into a database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I'm pulling data from a calendar feed and each event in the calendar has a unique `$EventID` string.  I'm using PHP.

I have a SQL database with an `Event_ID` column.  These IDs are strings.  I need to be able to compare my `$EventID` against the `Event_ID` column and put in in the database if it's not there.
I have a primary key set up to auto increment in the database, and I was thinking I can set up a loop to increment through those and compare each to the $EventID, but I'm wondering if there is a better way-maybe a PHP function I don't know about?

I've got a whole lot of code, but basically I've got:

```
<?php
$EventID = $event->id;  //This is the event ID

mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable
              (Event_ID, Date_added, Date_edited)
             VALUES 
              ('$EventID', '$dateAdded', '$lastEdited')");

?>
```

So how do I set up a conditional to check all the `Event_ID`s that are already in the database against the `$EventID`?

Comment: are you talking about a single table or whole db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `myTable`  WHERE `Event_ID`='$EventID' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
if (!mysql_num_rows($result))
 // INSERT QUERY
```

Check if the Event ID is present, If not insert it

Comment: You're making it to complicated. "Insert ignore" will have the same effect with just one query.

Comment: Insert ignore will work if the EventId is either the primary key or is set to unique, otherwise it'll be just be inserted again.

Comment: Insert Ignore didn't seem to work for me-but I blame my ineptness :)

Comment: Listen, maybe I am missing something... but what happens if the same code is executed by two different "threads"? Or "pages", this being PHP? Isn't this a classic case when concurrent access would result in duplication? Do you acquire a lock before doing the Select?

Comment: I think the concurrent access anomalies will be taken care by MySQL itself and we don't need to do anything specific to avoid it. If you want to explicitly take care of this, then [locking of tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) can be used.

Comment: The answer works for my needs.  It is a cron job that will run on my machine once an hour and will not run concurrently from another users machine.  The answer may not work for everyone, but it works for me-which is why I accepted it.  That's what SO is all about.

Comment: Yeah, ok. But I still think that whoever wrote the accepted answer should at least put a warning about this. Someone else may look for the same answer but in a different context, maybe in a month, or a year. SO is about *this*, too...

Answer (score 3):

You could just skip the "Select" query and do an "INSERT IGNORE" instead:

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO myTable
              (Event_ID, Date_added, Date_edited)
             VALUES 
              ('$EventID', '$dateAdded', '$lastEdited')");
```

this will leave existing Event_id's, and just add new records if required.

Comment: Actually-this may also answer my next question...if my $lastEdited variable has changed from before, then I need to rewrite the data in the row.  Would this also achieve this?

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO myTable
              (Event_ID, Date_added, Date_edited)
             VALUES 
              ('$EventID', '$dateAdded', '$lastEdited')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Date_added = '$dateAdded', Date_edited = '$lastEdited'`

Comment: No. Insert ignore will abort if you try to insert a row with a duplicate primary or unique key.